# Google timeline graph is not working showing "Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns" in html page

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Google timeline graph is not working, i converted python datatime to google date string , then i passed my array to google charts ,google chart is not shown and showing "Invalid data table format: must have 3 or 4 data columns" in html page.

Json object : `

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
   // var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
/*
      [
    ['Category', 'Name', {role: 'style'}, {type: 'date'}, {type: 'date'}],
    //'Date(2000, 8, 5)'
    ['BINGEN', '1', '#FF0000',     'Date(2014, 7, 1,12,01,01)', 'Date(2014, 7, 1,14,03,02)'],
    ['NRT', '1', '#228B22',        'Date(2014, 7, 1,10,10,10)',  'Date(2014, 7, 1,12,10,10)'],
    ['REGRESSION', '1', '#FF0000',  'Date(2014, 7, 1,09,10,12)',  'Date(2014, 7, 1,12,02,01)'],

    ['BINGEN', '2', '#FF0000',      'Date(2014, 7, 1,14,30,01)',  'Date(2014, 7, 1,16,03,02)'],
    ['NRT', '2', '#228B22',         'Date(2014, 7, 1,14,10,10)',  'Date(2014, 7, 1,16,10,10)'],
    ['REGRESSION', '2', '#FFFF00', 'Date(2014, 7, 1,14,10,12)',  'Date(2014, 7, 1,20,02,01)']
]);
*/


 var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "/jenkins/2017-02-10",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
 var my_data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
 my_data.splice(0, 0, ['Category', 'Name', {role: 'style'}, {type: 'date'}, {type: 'date'}]);
 var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(my_data);
    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
</script>

<div id="example3.1" style="height: 200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Below is the html page

Answer (score 2):

if you're using simple array data, as shown commented out in the question

you **cannot** feed that directly to --> `google.visualization.DataTable`

need to use static method instead --> `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`

```
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(my_data);
```

---

to feed directly to --> `google.visualization.DataTable`,

must be in the json format found here...

[Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)